# javassist Field check initialization

Tags: java, reflection, initialization, field, javassist

I am currently implementing an Annotation that forces the fields to respect a condition through javassist. I would like to check if a field is initialized when it is being read... so, currently, I am getting the classes by loading them when they are loaded by the VM through a `Translator.onLoad(ClassPool pool, String className)`, and using an `ExprEditor` on each class through overriding the `edit(FieldAccess arg)` method. Right now, I managed to inject code to check the condition by running the following method inside `onLoad` :

```
    private void processFields(FieldsAndMethods data) {
        final FieldsAndMethods copy = data;
        Stack<CtClass> classes = data.getThisClass();
        for(CtClass cc : classes ){
            try {
                cc.instrument(new ExprEditor(){

                @Override
                public void edit(FieldAccess arg) throws CannotCompileException{
                   try{
                        CtField field = arg.getField();
                        if(copy.getFields().contains(field) &&
                           field.hasAnnotation(Assertion.class)){

                            Assertion a =
                                ((Assertion)field.getAnnotation(Assertion.class))   
                            String condition = assertion.value();
                            String fieldName = field.getName();
                            String processCondition = 
                                transformCondition(condition, fieldName);

                            if(arg.isWriter()){

                                String code = "{if(" + evaledCondition + ")" +                                         
                                              "$proceed($$) ;" +
                                              "else throw new " + 
                                              "RuntimeException(\"The assertion " + 
                                                   condition + " is false.\");}";                                                                               
                                arg.replace(code);

            }else if (arg.isReader()){
                                //Here is where I would like to check if the field 
                                //has been initialized... 
            }

                        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                            System.out.println("could not find Annotation " + 
                            Assertion.class.getName() );
                        }catch(NotFoundException e){
                            System.out.println("could not find field " + 
                            arg.getFieldName() );
                        }                                       
                    }
                });
            } catch (CannotCompileException e) {                
                System.out.println("Could not interpret the expression");
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }       
    }

    private String transformCondition(String condition, String fieldName){
        return condition.replace(fieldName, "$1");      
    }
```

Could you point me in the right direction for finding out if a field has been initialized? Notice that a field can be either a primitive or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to inject code to check if the field is initialized OR do you want to check if the field is already initialized during your transformation?

Comment: Since the fields are constrained by the Assertion, I must to check if they have not been initialized (the default values may break the condition). Every field access to a non initialized variable (except, of course, any initialization in a constructor or a initializer).

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

I'll assume the following:

- By *field initialized* we are talking about fields that *are null*.
- Primitive types cannot be null so no bother to check them.

### The code

This example verification will work for both static and non static fields.

I've also created the code String in several lines for better readability. Being **arg** a *FieldAccess* object, you can write the following:

```
 if (arg.isReader() && !arg.getField().getType().isPrimitive()) {
  String code = "{ java.lang.Object var = $proceed();"
               +  "if(var == null) {"
                   + "java.lang.System.out.println(\"not initialized " + arg.getFieldName() + "\");"
               +  "}"
               + "$_=var;}";
            arg.replace(code);
        }
```

### Code Explanation

As you can see, in this small example I've used a few javassist identifiers, for the complete reference about this please read the [javassist official tutorial](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/%7Echiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#alter) (I'm linking to the section about code modifications).

Here is what each identifier used means:

- *$proceed()* : in the case of a field access this returns the value of the field.
- *$_* : this is an identifier that is mandatory when editing a FieldAccess in *read* mode. This token holds the value that will be used to set the field.

With this information it's easy to understand the code's idea:

1. Put the field value into an auxiliary object named *var*
2. Check if the field is null, if so print a warning with the field name
3. Set the fieldname with the value (either it's null or not);

I guess this already points you to the right direction. But let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Well... the thing was... it wasn't about checking if a value was null or not... a method can just as well do var=null... if i put an assertion that says `@Assertion("i>0")`, when a **var** is declared as `int i;`, it already breaks the assertion because it already has the default value, which is 0. Thanks for your answer though... I managed to do it through other means...

Comment: @CarlosFilipeCosta: Now I understand what's the *evaledCondition* in your example, it's the value from the Assertion annotation, correct? (The attribution wasn't present in it). Regarding `Asserting(i>0)` wouldn't be enough to change the `var==null` to the if `(evaledCondition)`?

Comment: @CarlosFilipeCosta: Also, if you still want help from SO users, which can include me re-editing my answer or answers from other users, my suggestion is to edit your answer to clarify a bit more what do you mean by a field has been initialized and maybe give a full example on what you want to do. If you are not interested in help anymore (since you said you found other means), I suggest you to post your own answer and accept it so it doesn't stay unanswered.